# Reconcile and sync two sets of data that have the same key value in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Ive got a list of URLS in a google sheet.

```
charlie.com |  apple   | 
alpha.com   |  orange  |
beta.com    |  banana  |
```

Ive got another list of data as a CSV (this could be imported into google sheets if it made the workflow easier) this data is as follows :

```
charlie.com |  one
alpha.com   |  three 
beta.com    |  seven
```

(note the URLS are the same, but the other data is different, the row order based upon the URLS is different also.

I want to combine these two sets of data so i get :

```
charlie.com |  one    |  apple
alpha.com   |  three  |  orange
beta.com    |  seven  |  banana
```

(so that all the data is correctly aligned using the URLS as the key value.

How can i do this ?

So far from doing some research on Google, ive been looking at a 3rd party paid plugin ([HERE](https://www.ablebits.com/google-sheets-add-ons/merge-sheets/index.php)) from that would enable me to do this, i feel its something that a spreadsheet would have input as a native function / workflow, but i cant seem to find the right search term for it when researching.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén added, see updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both lists of URLs have the same order and the same number of elements, you could use the Google Sheet array handling feature, i.e.:

```
={List1!A1:B3,List2!B1:B3}
```

If the real data from both list doesn't have the same number of elements but one list include all the elements of the other list you could do a "left join" or a "right join". The common ways to do this in Google Sheets is by using:

- VLOOKUP
- Using together INDEX and MATCH

If the real data from both list doesn't have the same number of elements and none list have all the elements of the other list but you don't want to miss any row you could do a "full outer join". A common way to do this in Google Sheets is to first create a list of all the values used as the row identifier, in this case the URLs, then do use the functions mentioned above two times, one for each list.

To create the list of URLs you could use the following formula:

```
=UNIQUE({List1!A1:A3;List2!A1:A3})
```

Related

- [Joining Two Tables and Merging Cells](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/76713/88163)
- [Cross referencing two sheets and pulling in values](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80163/88163)
- [Union of two lists of key-value pairs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/89554/88163)

References

- [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)
- [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)
- [Match](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)
- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)